# How to limit audio recording time using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, time, limit, android-audiorecord

How can I limit recording when using intents?

I tried this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",5);    
 startActivityForResult(intent,RQS_RECORDING);
```

This code works fine when I record video. Time is countdown from 5 to 0 and after 5 seconds recording automatically stops. But this limited time does not work when I record sound. Why?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 5);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
```

Why does this 5-second time limit not work when I record sound?

Comment: I'm afraid havent got an answer. It seems sollution does not exist :-)

Answer (score 10):

I Have a similar problem and I fixed my problem using below code snippet:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);
startActivityForResult(this, cameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

where CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST is my int type as:

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
```

Comment: Thank you! `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);` totally worked for me. :) Although I changed the number to 60, for 60 seconds.

Comment: Hi, For me, it works for video. For audio I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917361/11107110

Answer (score 2):

you should be try with MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
and mRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000) // 5 seconds;

Answer (score 1):

```
private void recordVideo() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

// set video quality
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set Video file
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

fileuri is your filepath. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
```

Comment: MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT is exactly the same thing of "android.intent.extra.durationLimit"